# UWP Community Toolkit

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-mobile, windows-community-toolkit

I added the UWP Community Toolkit to a project and am getting the following error while executing.

[image]

Has anyone ever experienced this?

Comment: have you tried to target your app for 14393? Does this fix it?

Comment: ok, click on the green checkbox to select the reply as answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: you should ask code related queries here!

Answer (score 6):

The [MSDN page of DropShadow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.composition.dropshadow) shows that the calls was added in Build 14393 (V1607):

**Device family**
Universal, introduced **version 10.0.14393.0**

So make sure you [target your app for Build 14393](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/08/02/universal-windows-apps-targeting-windows-10-anniversary-sdk/) and not the older 10586.

[image]

Comment: The UWP toolkit [docs](http://docs.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/controls/DropShadowPanel/) mention this as well.